# computing LBP feature on integral image with neon

Tags: c, neon

01--02--03--04
| v1 | v2 | v3 |
05--06--07--08
| v4 | cen | v5 |
09--10--11--12
| v6 | v7 | v8 |
13--14--15--16

The algorithm like as following:

```
p01 = ptr[0];
p02 = ptr[w1];
p03 = ptr[w1*2];
p04 = ptr[w1*3];

ptr +=  pitch;
p05 = ptr[0];
p06 = ptr[w1];
p07 = ptr[w1*2];
p08 = ptr[w1*3];

ptr +=  pitch;
p09 = ptr[0];
p10 = ptr[w1];
p11 = ptr[w1*2];
p12 = ptr[w1*3];

ptr +=  pitch;
p13 = ptr[0];
p14 = ptr[w1];
p15 = ptr[w1*2];
p16 = ptr[w1*3];

v1 = p06+p01-p02-p05;
v2 = p07+p02-p03-p06;
v3 = p08+p03-p04-p07;
v4 = p10+p05-p06-p09;
cent = p11+p06-p07-p10;
v5 = p12+p07-p08-p11;
v6 = p14+p09-p10-p13;
v7 = p15+p10-p11-p14;
v8 = p16+p11-p12-p15;

respond = 0
if (v1>cent) respond = respond+1;
if (v2>cent) respond = respond+2;
if (v3>cent) respond = respond+4;
if (v4>cent) respond = respond+8;
if (v5>cent) respond = respond+16;
if (v6>cent) respond = respond+32;
if (v7>cent) respond = respond+64;
if (v8>cent) respond = respond+128;
```

**ps:** w1 is fixed in each function call, and ptr is `unsigned int`

And how to efficient do it with neon.

Comment: What is the datatype of ptr, and does w1 have a fixed value?

Comment: If the values are stored far enough apart that no two are can be loaded in the same or adjacent cache lines, then there's probably no optimization to be had.  Otherwise, supposing that `pitch` is smaller than `w1`, you could achieve linear memory access by reading the values out in a different order: `v01`, `v05`, `v09`, `v02`, `v06`, `v10`, `v03`, `v07`, `v11`, `v04`, `v08`, `v12`.  That will increase the frequency of being able to serve accesses to elements of `ptr` from cache, instead of requiring a load from main memory.